# In an ASP control how can I get the text in a <Contentemplate> tag in the control code?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, user-controls

In my page ASP.net page I'm using a custom control like this:

```
<MyNamespace:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl">
<contenttemplate>
This is the text I want to use
</contenttemplate>
</MyNamespace:MyControl>
```

In the c# code of the control how can I obtain a string containing the text between the `<contentemplate>` tag (eg. "This is the text I want to use") ?
Can you give me the code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to make a templated control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx).